# How can i read data as i see in xlsx file from S3 bucket using Rstudio?

Tags: r, excel, amazon-s3, precision, data-conversion

I am trying to read a xlsm file from S3 bucket having some data as follows:

```
Date      Name  Percentage  CGPA
12/1/2020 Paula 72%         17.17
```

my code for reading is as below:

read_excel is inbuld func for reading excel file.
location_obj is my file path in S3 like "s3://data/file.xlsm"

```
s3_data<- s3read_using(FUN = read_excel, object = location_obj, sheet = "Sheet2")
```

but when i read, my data is converting its adding some extra decimals and percentage is converting into decimal and date is also changing.

refer below output:

```
Date      Name  Percentage              CGPA
44166     Paula 0.71699999999999997     17.170000000000002
```

i want data as it is in excel. please help

Comment: the data is not converting.. the original data IS like that.. (you may extend the column size to see it.

Comment: my data is in decimal only but in excel its rounding off and i want that data only but while reading in rstudio its giving all decimals

Comment: Can we set the "rounding off " Rstudio (after the value import). ?

Comment: no data get converted unto character so round off is not working there!

Comment: I had this trouble (the rounding part) when interfacing my excel data with python. Upon multiple unsuccessful tweak at the python code side (at the best of my might), I end up doing `=INT(A1*100+0.5)/100` to make   `0.71699999999999997` become `0.72` for each values in the column.